# JDBC Driver class not found in Hibernate program

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am making a simple mapping program in hibernate.

I am facing an error:

```
JDBC Driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

It gives an error on this line:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

`hibernate.cfg.xml` is correct. In the same configration other program are run. but this program give me error.

What is the reason that it throws this error?

Answer (score 4):

You need to get a MySQL driver and put it on your classpath.

A commonly-used driver is MySQL Connector/J. It can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Extract the package and make the jar available to your application.